Unable to create framework in Xcode 15 with Objective-C throwing error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"
I am trying to create objective C Network framework using Xcode 15 with minimum supported iOS version 14.0.
Here are the steps I am following:

I created New> Project> framework> Objective C> storyboard> Create.

Made NetworkManager.h file created by project to public.

Added two files MyNetworkRequest.h and MyNetworkRequest.m.

Made MyNetworkRequest.h > Public from inspector.

Added #import < NetworkManager/MyNetworkRequest.h> in the NetworkManager.h

From Project > Target > Build Setting > set SKIP_INSTALL = NO and Build Libraries for distribution = YES

Added script for making framework : select target from top bar> Edit scheme> Archive> Post action> Add run script> copy pasted following script:
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-Universal

# Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk 

iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}"    BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
    xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration     ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"     clean build
    # Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
    cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework"     "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# iOS - Copy the framework structure to the universal folder (clean it first)
rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
# Make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Copy Swift modules from iphonesimulator build (if it exists) to the copied     framework directory
BUILD_PRODUCTS="${SYMROOT}/../../../../Products"
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework"         "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework"

# Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the     copied framework directory
lipo -create -output 

"${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"     "${BUILD_PRODUCTS}/Debug-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"     "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

# Copy the framework to the project directory
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"

# Open the project directory in Finder
#open "${PROJECT_DIR}"
fi


build and make archive.

Open the archive by right clicking and show file content> does not contain framework in any enclosing folder.



I suggest to use SPM for framework creation, even if it's written in Objective-C

Thank you for your suggestion but the client needs framework directly. Hence I am stuck. I am able to build other framework using Xcode 12.3 on different machine. but not with the described specification.

Still you can build framework with SPM and use it directly
